# Power and Solar Energy

Tags: electricity

If power cannot go both ways at the same time through a wire, how do solar panels feed back to an electrical grid?

Comment: Why do you think power needs to go both ways at the same time ? At any point in time a household is either sourcing electric energy from the gird, or is exporting excess energy back to the grid - never both at the same time surely ?

Comment: Voting to re-open. A perfectly clear question with a good answer below.

Comment: The answer seems almost inherent in the premise: "If power cannot go both ways **at the same time** through a wire..." (Emphasis added.) Well, then I guess it goes one way at one time and the other way at another time. Either that or... use more than one wire.

Answer (score 0):

The "grid" is like the rotating shafts that used to power machinery in factories of the nineteenth century. An engine adds power to the shaft by torquing it in the same direction as its rotation. A machine that takes power from the shaft torques it in the opposite direction.

A generator adds power to the grid by trying to raise the grid voltage, while a consumer that takes power from the grid tends to pull the voltage down. A home with grid-tied solar (or other generating means) can do either thing, but as gandalf61 said, it can't do both at the same time. A single grid connection point cannot simultaneously try to raise and lower the grid voltage at the same time, just like how a single wheel on a shaft cannot torque the shaft in both directions at the same time.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, hence the question. As I was wondering how solar works when there is only one connection to the house, if that makes sense?

Comment: There is not only one connection to the house. To send/sell solar energy back to the grid company you need multiple connections. E.g., panel to smart home storage, smart home storage to grid, and of course these are not just single wires, there has to be a lot of electronics, including capacitors for storage and transistors for switching and microcontrollers for managing the process, etc.

Comment: @hft, All of those things can share a single connection. Where I live, a residence and its on-premises solar system connects to the grid through a single meter, and a single "drop" from the distribution line that runs down the street. If a grid-tied solar system is required to have its own separate meter in some other jurisdiction, then that's for legal, political, or administrative reasons, not for technical reasons.

Comment: It's a smart meter, there's a bunch of electronics, including a microcontroller, inside it.

Comment: @hft, The "smart" electronics in the meter enable the power company to sell power at different rates at different times of day, to buy back power at a different rate, to measure and bill for "power factor," to collect statistics, etc. But, no amount of smarts will allow power to flow in both directions through the same meter and drop at the same time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I know that. What are you talking about? See my comment on OP's question.